# Getting error when I connect sails js with mysql (node - v7.5.0)

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

```
error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
error: Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Could not connect to MySQL:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3306
    at afterwards (/root/sails/sailsUserApp/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:72:13)
    at /root/sails/sailsUserApp/node_modules/sails-mysql/lib/connections/spawn.js:40:7
    at Handshake.onConnect [as _callback] (/root/sails/sailsUserApp/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Pool.js:54:9)
    at Handshake.Sequence.end (/root/sails/sailsUserApp/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:96:24)
    at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/root/sails/sailsUserApp/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:364:14)
    at PoolConnection.Connection._handleNetworkError (/root/sails/sailsUserApp/node_modules/sails-mysql/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:421:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1280:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

**connection.js -**

```
Mysql: 
{
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root', //optional
    password: 'sipl@1234', //optional
    database: 'sails_users' //optional
}
```

**models.js** - `connection: 'Mysql',`

I am unable to figure-out the issue. *port: 3306* is already mentioned in the configuration.

Comment: Where do you specify database configuration, Can you add that part?

Comment: in connections.js file -
Mysql: {
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '3306',
    user: 'root', //optional
    password: 'sipl@1234', //optional
    database: 'sails_users' //optional
  },

Comment: Are you able to connect to MySQL using the same credentials from command line e.g. `mysql -u root -psipl@1234 sails_users` ? Please update your question with content of your `connections.js` file.

Comment: Yes, I and able to connect my phpmyadmin with this credentials directly...

But when I try to connect mysql with sails, so it getting above error...

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL connection parameters will depend on the MySQL configuration. The configuration file location and default connection access control list will depend on the OS that MySQL is running on and the options that were passed to the installation.

It may be expecting a Unix Socket connection rather than a TCP connection. Review your MySQL configuration file to see which connections and users are allowed. If it is allowing only socket connections there will be a specific unix socket it is expecting to use.

With that information you can set the configuration parameters accordingly.

To use a socket connection the parameters would be:

```
Mysql: 
{
    adapter: 'sails-mysql',
    socketPath: 'path-to-socket/mysql.sock',
    user: 'mysql-user',
    password: 'mysql-password',
    database: 'mysql-database'
}
```